# Using abstract method with generic list as return type in java

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, abstract

im trying to build this abstract method within an abstract class and using it in one of my subclasses and it's return type shall be a List / ArrayList. I'm really struggling with the syntax, and most of the previous asked question are not referring to my special issue.

Most important for me to describe it in easy words.

1. Let me use a method
2. Output (return) of that method should be a list of ...I don't what objects yet
3. And it's original declaration is abstract

**Here the abstract class***

```
private int employeeID;
    private String name, sID, department;
    private double salary;

    // Constructor (empty)
    public Employee() {

    }

    // Constructor => Every Employee has at least this attributes => Subclasses may have additonal attributes
    public Employee(int employeeID, String name, String sID, double salary, String department) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.name = name;
        this.sID = sID;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = department;
    }

    // Getters and Setters below
    //.......

 // Abstract method with generic list as return type
    public abstract <T> List<T> read(String path);
```

***Here is the Subclass***

```
public class Clerk extends Employee {

    public Clerk() {

    }

    public Clerk(int employeeID, String name, String sID, double salary, String department) {
        super(employeeID, name, sID, salary, department);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> List<T> read(String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String line = null;
        List<Clerk> clerk = new ArrayList<Clerk>();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            reader.readLine();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] clerkValues = line.split(";");
                clerk.add(new Clerk(Integer.parseInt(clerkValues[0]), clerkValues[1], clerkValues[2], Double.parseDouble(clerkValues[3]), clerkValues[4]));

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return clerk; // Error here,Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Clerk> to List<T>
```

---

I'm always getting an error. And I don't want to build the superclass (Employee) as a generic Class like =>

```
 public abstract class Employee <T>{
    // Code here
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Sorry for missing the classname of abstaract class => It's public abstract class Employee{}

Comment: You may not want to build the superclass as a generic class, but you're going to have to.

Comment: Is it not possible to use an abstract generic method only? I mean the variables for the objects won't change at all. Only in the subclass I may add a class to build new objects. Example "Director", "Janitor", "Manager" etc...

Comment: The variables for the objects won't change, but when you write `public <T> List<T> myFunction`, `myFunction` has to work for _all_ values of `T`, not just the one associated with a particular class.  To change that, `T` has to be a generic parameter of the type.

Comment: Are you sure you need the abstract method? If so, can it return `List<Employee>` without specialization in the subclass? What do the callers of this code look like?

Comment: Your override isn't returning a list of `T`. Rather it's a list of `Clerk`.  Afaik, there's no super (abstract) class method signature that  can be overridden to return different list types, which seems to be what you're attempting.  Consider rewriting your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish with this method. (Needing a `Clerk` instance to read a list of `Clerk`s doesn't make much sense.)  Then someone can suggest an appropriate pattern.

Comment: Besides what @TimMoore proposed in his answer, the only alternative "safe" option is to actually make your superclass generic: `abstract static class Employee<T extends Employee<T>>` to ensure that a particular `T` is a subclass of `Employee` whenever a class extends your Employee. `class Clerk extends Employee<Clerk>` and then you're good to go:  `public List<Clerk> read(String path) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the method in `Employee` like this:

```
public abstract List<? extends Employee> read(String path);
```

You could translate this to English like this "read returns a list of some unknown type of employee". You'll be able to iterate the list and otherwise read from it, and treat elements as `Employee`. You won't be able to add new `Employee` elements to the list, or otherwise pass `Employee` elements as parameters to methods. For this use case, that is probably fine.

You can override it in `Clerk` and the other subclasses with method signatures like this:

```
public List<Clerk> read(String path)
```

This works because `List<Clerk>` is a *subtype* of `List<? extends Clerk>`, and Java allows you to override a method with the overriding method returning a more specific type than the method it overrides.

If you then call `read` on a reference of type `Clerk`, the return type will be `List<Clerk>`, as expected.

This would not work if the `Employee` class returned `List<Employee>` instead of `List<? extends Employee>`, because `List` is *invariant* and therefore `List<Clerk>` is *not* a subtype of `List<Employee>`. To understand why that is, consider that a `List<Employee>` *does* allow you to add new `Employee` elements to it. If the actual type of the list were `List<Clerk>`, but the compiler allowed adding other types of `Employee` to the list that are not instances of `Clerk`, it would violate the expectation that the list only contained `Clerk` elements, and likely lead to runtime errors.

I do agree with Gene's comment that it doesn't make much sense to have these methods on instances of `Employee` and `Clerk`. Perhaps having an `EmployeeReader` interface and `ClerkReader` implementation would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation @Tim Moore. It worked for me in a similar way, with the help of the wildcard "?" operator. I've tried your described approach and worked also well. 

Thank you all again for your support guys.